# TypeORM disable logging via .env config

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

Even tho I put `TYPEORM_LOGGING=false`, SQL query logs are still bloating the console:

[image]

Is there any way to explicitly disable these logs? Seems like .env configuration doesn't affect it or is conflicted.

Comment: I just came across the similar problem and get a better approach.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500730/limit-the-logging-from-typeorm-instead-of-disabling

Answer (score 4):

You can either use ormconfig.js file by using `logging: false` as described here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md

```
{
    name: "mysql",
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "test",
    password: "test",
    database: "test",
    ...
    logging: false
}
```

using ormconfig.js file will be more flexible compared with env variables.
About .env, can you guarantee that env variable has expected value during runtime? If env defined before reading .env file, dotenv cant overwrite it  as I know

Answer (score 2):

You can enable/disable logging of all queries and errors by simply setting logging: true/false in data source options:

```
{
    name: "....",
    type: "....",
    host: "localhost",
    port: ...,
    username: "test",
    password: "test",
    database: "test",
    ...
    logging: true // or false
}
```

You can also enable different types of logging in data source options:

```
{
    host: "localhost",
    ...
    logging: ["query", "error"]
}
```

If you want to enable logging of failed queries only then only add error:

```
{
    host: "localhost",
    ...
    logging: ["error"]
}
```

There are other options you can use:

> - query - logs all queries.
> - error - logs all failed queries and errors.
> - schema - logs the schema build process.
> - warn - logs internal orm warnings.
> - info - logs internal orm informative messages.
> - log - logs internal orm log messages.

You can specify as many options as needed. If you want to enable all logging you can simply specify logging: "all":

```
{
    host: "localhost",
    ...
    logging: "all"
}
```